# Is the getRow() method for Google DataTable deprecated?

Tags: datatable, google-api, google-visualization, google-datatable

I was trying to use the getRow() method (described [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/dev/dsl_javadocs/com/google/visualization/datasource/datatable/DataTable#getRow%28int%29))

But when running my webpage I get `"Uncaught TypeError: Object #<U> has no method 'getRow' "`.

Has this function been deprecated ? If not, how can I make sure I can use it ?

Here is my code :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
google.load('visualization', '1',{'packages': ['table']});
```

and then later on (both `data` and `dataToAdd` are `DataTable()`):

```
data.addRow(dataToAdd.getRow(0));
```

Comment: got code? its not been deprecated according to the specs.

Comment: added the code in the main question

Comment: I don't see the problem - perhaps you could separate the 2 functions and see what the problem is that way. I mean instead of using getRow() inside addRow() get the row first and then add it later. Might clarify the issue.

Comment: That doesn't change anything. Did you get the function to work on one of your webpages ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround using

```
(dataToAdd.K).map(function tmp(x) {return(x["c"])})
```

This gives you the array of rows in your `dataToAdd` DataTable().

Answer (score 3):

If you read: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#google.visualization.arraytodatatable

You will find a function `getValue(rowIndex, columnIndex)`

In my example I have a list of lat/lons, of which I ensure are valid, then render. Upon clicking a lat/lon I want to do something with the lat/lons. Scroll down to the bottom to see the usage of DataTable.getValue()

```
var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
dataTable.addColumn('number', 'Latitude');
dataTable.addColumn('number', 'Longitude');
dataTable.addColumn('string', 'Name');

$.each(data, function(i, o) {
    var lat = parseFloat(o.lat);
    var lon = parseFloat(o.lon);
    var name = o.name;
    if(LIB.Location.isLatLonValid([lat, lon])) {
        var row = [lat, lon, name];
        dataTable.addRow(row);
    }
});

var options = {
    width : 550
    ,height : 240
    ,region: country
    ,legend: 'none'
    ,showTip : false
    ,mapType : 'normal'
};

var chart = new google.visualization.Map(document.getElementById('location_pin_chart'));
chart.draw(dataTable, options);
// handle clicking on pin
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart,'select', function(e) {
    var selection = chart.getSelection();
    var lat = dataTable.getValue(selection[0].row, 0); // HERE is where I get the value!
    var lon = dataTable.getValue(selection[0].row, 1);
    alert(lat + ", " + lon);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[Capo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17418541/4157871) answer is correct, still here is an similar way

```
dataToAdd.fg
```

This also gives direct access to the internal `dataToAdd` DataTable() array